# ZaP DOM based XSS alert when used nginx pam for authentication

Tags: nginx, browser, xss, pam, zap

In our application we have the basic website written in basic Html and javascript no framework,  using the nginx web-server and the Pam authentication module is used with basic authentication. Pam module basically uses the browser login prompt for login. When this authentication is enabled ZAP tool is detecting DOM based XSS alert with all the resources present. Even with empty page when auth enabled showing DOM vulnerability

('  Attack Payload: #jaVasCript:/*-/*`/*\\`/*'/*"/**/(/* */oNcliCk=alert() '
')//%0D%0A%0d%0a//</stYle/</titLe/</teXtarEa/</scRipt/--!>\x3csVg/<sVg/oNloAd=alert()//>\x3e')
Response Body:\n \n'
40026 Cross Site Scripting (DOM Based) https:///ZeroClipboard.js#jaVasCript:/*-/*`/*\`/*'/*"/**/(/* */oNcliCk=alert() )//%0D%0A%0d%0a//</stYle/</titLe/</teXtarEa/</scRipt/--!>\x3csVg/<sVg/oNloAd=alert()//>\x3e

Can anyone please check and help me how to fix this.

Comment: Sounds similar to: https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/issues/6484

Comment: Hi @Kingthorin , Thanks for reply. Yes indeed it looks similar. If I disable authentication pop up its not showing any DOM alert. Does it mean for all POP-up coming ZAP shows as DOM based alert?

Comment: Currently, until that issue is fixed it seems.